# Por que este resultado esta dando como 0 em Java?

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um programa em que tem uma pequena e simples calculadora, basicamente o usuário terá as expressões matemáticas (+,-,*,/) e poderá escolher entre uma delas para em seguida o  resultado aparecer na tela. Mas por algumas razão não está funcionando e ele retorna como 0 o resultado.

Meu código :

```
        int n1 = 20; //o primeiro número
        int n2 = 20; //o segundo número
        int res = 0;
        String op;

        op = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("+ " + 
            "\n - " + 
            "\n * " +
            "\n /");

        if(op == "+") {
            res = n1+n2; //retorna 0, ao invés de 40.
        }
        else if(op == "-") {
            res = n1-n2;//somente aqui que deve retornar 0.
        }
        else if(op == "*") {
            res = n1*n2;//retorna 0, ao invés de 400.
        }
        else if(op == "/") {
            res = n1/n2;//retorna 0, ao invés de 1.
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Result : " + res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui encontrar o erro, estava nos `if` em que ele pulava a parte de verificação dentro dos `if` e retornava como 0 o resultado pois `res = 0`.

Meu código arrumado :

```
        int n1 = 20;
        int n2 = 20;
        int res = 0;
        String op;

        op = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("+ " + 
            "\n - " + 
            "\n * " +
            "\n /");

        if(op.equals("+")) {
            res = n1+n2;
        }
        else if(op.equals("-")) {
            res = n1-n2;
        }
        else if(op.equals("*")) {
            res = n1*n2;
        }
        else if(op.equals("/")) {
            res = n1/n2;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Result : " + res);
```

Comment: Por favor, marque a sua resposta como solução.